# Disjoint unions and countability

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

First, let me say that when I say *countable* set I mean a set whose cardinality is *less than or equal* to the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$. A set whose cardinality is *strictly equal* to the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ will be called *countably infinite*.

Also, $\bigsqcup_{i \in I} X_i = \{ (i,x) \in I \times\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i \mid x \in X_i \}$. Of course, $|\bigcup_{i \in I} X_i| \leq |\bigsqcup_{i \in I} X_i|$.

Let $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ be an indexed family with the index set $I$.

It is widely known that if $I$ is countable (resp., countably infinite) and $\forall i \in I, X_i$ is countable (resp., countable infinite), then $\bigsqcup_{i \in I} X_i$ is itself countable (resp., countable infinite).

However, what if $I \neq \varnothing$ and

- $(1)$ $I$ is *countably infinite* but each $X_i$ is only known to be *countable*? That is, there is a *bijection* $f\colon I\to\mathbb{N}$ and a family $(f_i)_{i \in I}$ of *injections* $X_i\to\mathbb{N}$.
- $(2)$ And what if each $X_i$ is *countably infinite* while $I$ is just *countable*? That is, there is an *injection* $f\colon I\to\mathbb{N}$ and a family $(f_i)_{i \in I}$ of *injections* $X_i\to\mathbb{N}$.

The intuition tells me that in both cases $(1)$ and $(2)$ the disjoint union $\bigsqcup_{i \in I} X_i$ will be countably infinite. However, how to prove it rigorously is another question entirely.

**Remark.** To construct a family $(f_i)_{i \in I}$ of injections (resp., bijections) $X_i\to\mathbb{N}$ knowing only that each $X_i$ is countable (resp., countably infinite) we need the axiom schema of replacement to obtain a set of sets of injections $X_i\to\mathbb{N}$ (each for every $i \in I$) and the axiom of choice to obtain a choice function of such set.

**P.S.** I don't know whether I should tag this as *elementary set theory* or *set theory*. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Since the empty set is countable, (1) is not necessarily infinite, and neither is (2) if $I=\emptyset$.

Comment: While I agree it's helpful, this seems more of an oversight on the original intention. If the OP edits now, what's the worth of your answer?

Comment: Thanks! Edited.